# get_next_post() not working

Tags: posts

I'm using **get_next_post()** and **get_previous_post()** in single.php.
But the problem is it's not displaying **Next** post on all single posts.
The previous post is displaying on every single page fine but next post is just displaying on first post.
Here is my code:

```
global $post;
$prevPost = get_previous_post();
$nextPost = get_next_post();
 /* echo '<pre>';
print_r($nextPost);
exit();*/
<?php 
    if($prevPost) {

?>
    <div class="prev">
        <h3><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($prevPost); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($prevPost); ?></a></h3>
        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( $prevPost->post_content , '40' ); ?></p>     
         <a class="read-more" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($prevPost); ?>">More...</a>
    </div>
<?php

    }

    if($nextPost) {

    ?>

    <div class="post-next">
        <h4><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($nextPost); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($nextPost); ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( $nextPost->post_content , '35' ); ?></p>

        <a class="previous" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($nextPost); ?>">More...</a>
    </div>
<?php

    } // end if
?>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly!

Comment: Hi Dan9 check now.

Comment: Underlying logic is quite involved and runs raw SQL. Hard to guess why would it be failing.

Answer (score 1):

Only a guess but you might need

```
global $post
```

before your code. According to the Codex docs for the functions you are using the return values are

> Null if global $post is not set.

Also you might want to use their suggested logicals:

```
if (!empty( $prev_post ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but i already **global $post;** on the top of file and i also tried this  **if (!empty( $prev_post ))** but not working :( .

Its showing the next post on just first post.

Comment: I would do more debugging then a print_r; do something like a var_dump($prevPost) so you can see the full post array data being returned.

Comment: i already checked by print_r($nextPost) but it returns nothing. and print_r($prevPost) returns the post object.

Comment: That's why I suggest using var_dump to print the entire array, you can often debug if you know what info Wordpress is passing through the array. Seeing a post object just tells you it does or does not exist.